# Deny websites to verify installed extensions in Firefox

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, privacy

When I visit websites they automatically detect which Browser I'm using and which extensions are installed on the browser (besides a bunch of other information). How do i deny websites access to this information regarding the list of installed extensions (type of browser is okay)?

The solution suggested [here](https://superuser.com/questions/292666/how-to-disable-permission-to-read-system-fonts-and-browser-plugin-details-in) for Firefox does not work anymore since the menu item is no longer part of the configuration.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable permission to read 'System Fonts' and 'Browser Plugin Details' in Chrome and Firefox](http://superuser.com/questions/292666/how-to-disable-permission-to-read-system-fonts-and-browser-plugin-details-in)

Comment: Thanks for the link. The solution provided there does not work anymore.

Comment: There's 5 or 6 answers there, which "solution" did you try?  Regardless, since it's still the same *question*, if you'd like newer/different answers please help out the site (answer questions, etc.) to [earn some rep](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), and then use that rep to put [a bounty](http://superuser.com/help/bounty) on the existing question, along with some info about what ways the existing solutions didn't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Disable `JavaScript`.

You can also try `Random Agent Spoofer`.

Answer (score 0):

@user3486470 is right with Random Agent Spoofer. -- Because it recently added options to turn off plugin enumeration: https://github.com/dillbyrne/random-agent-spoofer/issues/283

As an alternative, as showed in Mechazawa's comment in that link, you can use his Greasemonkey or Tampermonkey script (both firefox and chrome) to take care of this without any extension.

I can confirm that this shows plugins as "undefined" in the panopticlick test.