# How I can change my GPU for web sites?

Tags: browser, gpu, privacy, web

On [this site](http://webkay.robinlinus.com/), I can see that it detects my GPU.

Is there any way to change it to another GPU for the web-browser, or to make it undetectable without turning off JavaScript?

Comment: Impossible to avoid such identification. See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1478926/8672) of mine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable permission to read 'System Fonts' and 'Browser Plugin Details' in Chrome and Firefox](https://superuser.com/questions/292666/how-to-disable-permission-to-read-system-fonts-and-browser-plugin-details-in)

Answer (score 0):

My Chrome seems to reveal this information too. I just tried that website on Firefox, and it is then unable to tell my GPU (along with the other things, such as battery, Social Media or what not).